# React Three Fiber | Rotate Camera or Scene Not Working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am using the [@react-three/fiber](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/hooks) to create a canvas and then some objects inside the canvas. In certain cases I want the scene to be inverted in front of me. I tried using the `useThree` hook but that doesn't seem to work at all.

Here's my canvas

```js
<Canvas >
            <OrbitControls maxDistance={900} minDistance={30} enablePan={true} ></OrbitControls>
            {(props.socketType == constants.socketNames.leroyMerlin) && <LampLoader index={0} />}
            {(props.socketType == constants.socketNames.e27) && <LampLoader index={1} />}
            <pointLight position={[0, 200, 200]} intensity={0.5} />
            <ambientLight intensity={0.3} />
            <Environment near={1} far={1000} resolution={256} preset="warehouse" />
            <mesh >
                <sphereBufferGeometry />
                <meshStandardMaterial color="hotpink" />
            </mesh>
            {
                props.meshObject != undefined ? <primitive object={props.meshObject} position={[0, 0, 0]} /> : <></>
            }
            <CameraRotator />
        </Canvas>
```

Here's the camera rotator function:

```js
function CameraRotator() {
    const stuff = useThree();

    stuff.camera.rotateOnWorldAxis(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Math.PI) //doesn't work
    //    stuff.camera.rotateOnAxis(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Math.PI) doesn't work
    //    stuff.scene.rotateOnAxis(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Math.PI) doesn't work
    //    stuff.scene.rotateOnWorldAxis(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Math.PI) doesn't work
    console.log(stuff);
}
```

[image]

This is the lamp, I just want to flip it upside down is all.
before you ask, yes I've tried taking out the orbit controls and it still doesn't work but ideally I want a solution where the orbit controls work and the object is flipped.